# Uploading a file to a modem using an AT command

Tags: at-command

Hello I have a Quectel BG95 modem that I am trying to upload an SSL cacert.pem to for performing server authentication, but I am very confused by the process (although I am a total noob at this). There are two manufacturer manuals guiding me through the process: [BG95&BG77&BG600L Series SSL Application Note](https://www.quectel.com/download/quectel_bg95bg77bg600l_series_ssl_application_note_v1-1) and the second: [BG95&BG77&BG600L Series FILE Application Note](https://www.dragino.com/downloads/downloads/datasheet/other_vendors/BG95/Software/Quectel_BG95&BG77&BG600L_Series_FILE_Application_Note_V1.1.pdf).  The first requires an account to download, but the second does not.

In the SSL application note they tell you to upload the cacert using a specific AT command.  Great but I am wondering this file is on my server even if I punch in this AT command how will the file get to the modem?  I have a USB port on the modem and I can connect to it but still how will this work, does anyone have a clue?

[image: ssl ap note excerpt1]

[image: ssl ap note excerpt2]

They list an example of uploading a .psk file, which confuses me because I am trying to upload a .pem file for the key.

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

After sending the upload command with the correct parametres to the modem, the device switches to DATA mode, that is it either waits for data or sends the data you requested, what I do is to open another terminal without closing the first one and send the binary file to same port where the modem is connected, after the modem receives the number of bytes stated in the command parametres then the first terminal where you gave the upload command returns to COMMAND mode. I am using this method to upload the GPS almanac, the problem is that the uploaded file seems to be corrupted perhaps due to incorrect synchronisation. Try this trick to see if it works for your text file.